# deinit is executed before viewDidLoad

Tags: swift

It does not make sense to say "deinit is executed before viewDidLoad". If not witnessed by myself, I never believe it. However, it 100% really happens here on my Project(Xcode8 and Swift2.3).

Is there any reason for this weird to happen?

Comment: please show us your code.

Comment: Do you see viewDidLoad being actually called after the deinit? Please clarify.

Comment: @MirekE viewDidLoad is never called

Answer (score 1):

Sure, initialize your view controller to a local variable, don't access its view or add it to the view hierarchy and leave the current scope. The view controller will deinit and `viewDidLoad()` will never have been called.

Keep in mind that `viewDidLoad()` is only called the first time the view controller's `view` property is explicitly accessed, or when `loadView()` or `loadViewIfNeeded()` are called on the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar experience and found I was mistakenly calling the same segue twice.  The first view controller constructed got de-initialized immediately (pre viewDidLoad).